# date and time value wont print on input date time format form box

Tags: php

Well i use input type date/time to store value to mysql which stored data as

Date: 2020-08-26T18:30:00.000Z
Time: 1969-12-31T19:03:00.000Z

now to print on edit form i did the following but it just dont show the value in the form

```
<label for="callback_date">Callback Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="callback_date" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['callback_date']));?>"class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <label for="callback_time">Callback Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="callback_time" value="<?php echo date("h:i A", strtotime($row['callback_time']));?>"  class="form-control" />
```

Could someone show me the right way to get it done?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the right format to put date or time in the input.

Your edited code with right format :

```
<label for="callback_date">Callback Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="callback_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['callback_date']));?>"class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <label for="callback_time">Callback Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="callback_time" value="<?php echo date("H:i", strtotime($row['callback_time']));?>"  class="form-control" />
```

For more explication take a look to this two links :

For the time : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/time
For the date : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date

Comment: Thanks @Inazo, well i did try this way too but i guess something is wrong my my pc things taking long to take effect.